# Can Wall of Stone make a box?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

[Wall of Stone](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=365) says:

> You shape a wall of solid stone. You create a 1-inch-thick wall of stone up to 120 feet long, and 20 feet high. You can shape the wall's path, placing each 5 feet of the wall on the border between squares. The wall doesn't need to stand vertically, so you can use it to form a bridge or set of stairs, for example. You must conjure the wall in an unbroken open space so its edges don't pass through any creatures or objects, or the spell is lost.

I'm not sure if I'm just carrying over interpretations from other systems or not, but can Wall of Stone be used to enclose a creature in a box? Not, not just a cage (which the spell obviously can use), but a box with a roof over it and everything. It doesn't really seem like a "wall" to me, but if the wall can "twist" (i.e. change from vertical to horizontal orientation), then it seems like you could start with the cage, and then continue the "wall" off the top of the last segment of the cage. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, because of how the [rules on shapable walls](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=302) are written

The rules for Wall spells stipulate:

> Some walls can be shaped; you can manipulate the wall into a form other than a straight line, choosing its contiguous path square by square. The path of a shaped wall can’t enter the same space more than once, but it can double back so one section is adjacent to another section of the wall.

There would be cracks at a couple edges of your prison (letting in air and potentially important to the narrative), but you are able to perform as many 90 degree turns as you wish; there doesn't seem to be a limit on if those squares are on the same axis.

### I would lean against it, as GM

The 7th level spell Force Cage provides a similar (albeit improved in flexibility) effect as using Wall of Stone as such which makes me think that the exact effect is probably a 6th level spell-equivalent effect. See also the 6th level Reverse Gravity which provides similar but different area control. If a player was particularly interested in using the spell as such, I'd likely allow it as a bonus effect if the spell was Hightened, though.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes.

> ***The wall doesn't need to stand vertically***, so you can use it to form a bridge or set of stairs, for example.

Comment: It's less of the "vertical standing" that confuses me, and more of whether it can change orientation. The vertical standing clause seems to be about the creation of stairs and bridges, both of which are horizontal standing, and both of which do not involve twisting. Maybe I'm just overthinking it, which is possible, this iteration of the spell seems much more open ended than the other editions I've used it in.

Comment: @ESCE The 'set of stairs' *example* shows that it can fold at 90 degrees, and making a box follows all the other rules.

Comment: That still doesn't address the "twisting" question. I'm aware (and agree) that 90 degree turns are fine. But to complete the box with a lid, you'd have to do a 90 degree turn into a new dimension. If that makes any sense?

Comment: @ESCE Stairs have the same shape condition as a box. The vertical risers and horizontal runners are oriented along different planes, yet stairs are an explicit use of the spell. A box has four vertical walls, changing direction at corners as the caster dictates, and a horizontal 'lid'. (But not bottom, due to collision with feet.)